# C# WPF увеличение размера Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Имеется такой вопрос (подскажите просто куда копать) как в рамках MVVM сделать интерфейс похожий так тот, который на скрине, чтобы размер grid, самой области, увеличивался в зависимости от кол-ва содержимого (и был больше размера окна), с полосами прокрутки. И как грамотно отображать содержимое в таком же формате? Со стрелочками, группировкой и т.д.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы уверены, что вам нужен грид, а не канвас?

Comment: Абсолютно не уверен

Comment: ну я ответ не даю, просто какие то ключевые слова для вас, типа [wpf diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48926170/best-way-to-model-block-diagrams-in-wpf), WPF Diagram Designer ([1](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22952/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part-1), [2](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23265/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part-2)), что то готовое ( [1](https://www.mindfusion.eu/wpf-diagram.html), [2](https://www.syncfusion.com/wpf-ui-controls/diagram) )

Comment: А как можно отображать элементы в таком же формате, фото и подпись?

Comment: Сделайте отдельный контрол с тем видом, что вам надо, и поместите его на канвас

Comment: Покажите что вы пробовали сделать и что не получилось?